# try catch raise error

Tags: sql-server

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему два аналогичных пакета, а вывод разный?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
BEGIN TRY
    RAISERROR('Деление на ноль', 11, 3);
    PRINT 'TRY'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   PRINT 'CATCH'
END CATCH;
GO

BEGIN TRY        
    RAISERROR('Деление на ноль', 10, 3);
    PRINT 'TRY'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   PRINT 'CATCH'
END CATCH;
GO
```

Comment: А Вы [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) читали? _Ошибка возвращается вызывающему объекту, если инструкция RAISERROR вызывается: [...] с уровнем серьезности, равным 10 и менее в блоке TRY_

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ. Думаю это стоит процитировать

> Цитата

Инструкция PRINT не зависит от блоков TRY, в то время как инструкция RAISERROR, выполняемая с уровнем серьезности от 11 до 19 в блоке TRY, передает управление процессом соответствующему блоку CATCH. Задайте уровень серьезности, равный 10 или меньше, чтобы инструкция RAISERROR возвращала сообщения из блока TRY без вызова блока CATCH.